# Reverse state in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement sorting functionality in my notes app but have some problems with it. My sort function must just reverse an array of notes but it does not work.

```
I have a state with notes:

    export const initialState = {
      notes: [
        {
          id: nanoid(),
          text: '',
          date: '',
        },
      ],
    }
```

```
Action:

    export const sortNoteAction = ([notes]) => ({
      type: SORT_NOTE,
      payload: [notes],
    })
```

```
Reducer:

    export default function notes(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
      switch (type) {
        case SORT_NOTE: {
          return {
            ...state,
            notes: [payload].reverse(),
          }
        }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Action:

    export const sortNoteAction = (notes=[]) => ({
      type: SORT_NOTE,
      payload: notes,
    })


Reducer:

    export default function notes(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SORT_NOTE: {
          return {
            ...state,
            notes: action.payload.reverse(),
          }
        }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because you are essentially sorting a list with just one item. If you change `[notes]` to `notes` (2 occurrences) and `[payload]` to `payload` (1 occurrence) it will probably work